# An alias of a sqlalchemy class?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is my base class

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PRODUCT'
    __table_args__ = {'quote':False}

    ...
    id = Column(Integer, name='id_prod', primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String(100),name='id_typ_prod')

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}
```

So, naturally we have a number of classes that extends from this Product, e.g. Phone and Cable, each of them maps to its own table.

```
class Phone (Product):
    __tablename__ = 'PHONE'
    ...
```

Now for some reasons now I want to create a 'alias' class, a class that does not have a corresponding table in database. Something like this:

```
class VapourWare(Product):
     ...
```

If I do

```
class VapourWare(Product):
    __tablename__ = 'PRODUCT'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity':'VapourWare'}
```

It seems to work. But is it the right or recommended way? I am repeating `__tablename__ = 'PRODUCT'` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some degree it depends on what you're trying to achieve, but from your example it seems that what you're trying to do is called [Single-Table Inheritence](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance) in the SA Docs. The example listed on the linked page seems very much like your example, with `Employee == Product` and `Manager == VapourWare` (insert Dilbert joke here).